# Difference between two dates in minute, hours javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I want to find difference between two dates. I have tried this code but it gives me wrong values. I want get total minutes between two dates, so I am converting hours to minutes and adding to minutes.

```
var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
var diffHrs = Math.round((hourDiff % 86400000) / 3600000);
var diffMins = Math.round(((hourDiff % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
diffMins = diffMins + (diffHrs * 60);
```

Here `timeEnd` is `Mon Jan 01 2007 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`,

and `timeStart` is `Mon Jan 01 2007 11:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Here if hours difference I am getting `1`, it should be `0` and minutes I am getting `30` that is right. But hours should be `0`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var diffHrs = Math.floor((hourDiff % 86400000) / 3600000);
```

`Math.round` rounded the `0.5` hour difference up to `1`. You only want to get the "full" hours in your hours variable, do you remove all the minutes from the variable with the `Math.floor()`

Answer (score 28):

Try this code (uses ms as initial units)

```
var timeStart = new Date("Mon Jan 01 2007 11:00:00 GMT+0530").getTime();
var timeEnd = new Date("Mon Jan 01 2007 11:30:00 GMT+0530").getTime();
var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; //in ms
var secDiff = hourDiff / 1000; //in s
var minDiff = hourDiff / 60 / 1000; //in minutes
var hDiff = hourDiff / 3600 / 1000; //in hours
var humanReadable = {};
humanReadable.hours = Math.floor(hDiff);
humanReadable.minutes = minDiff - 60 * humanReadable.hours;
console.log(humanReadable); //{hours: 0, minutes: 30}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2WgW/

Comment: This comes down to the same suggestion as I made: "Use `Math.floor()`".
Try to explain why your answer works, instead of only dumping some code in an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, that's true, it's about `Math.floor`. My answer elaborates a bit the way the ms are converted into seconds, minutes, and hours. That's it.

Comment: It doesn't explain why this code results in the answer the user wants. You're just using a different method to get the data.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var startDate = new Date('Jan 01 2007 11:00:00');
var endDate = new Date('Jan 01 2007 11:30:00');
var starthour = parseInt(startDate.getHours());
var endhour = parseInt(endDate.getHours());

if(starthour>endhour){
    alert('Hours diff:' + parseInt(starthour-endhour));
}
else{
    alert('Hours diff:' + parseInt(endhour-starthour));
}
```

And here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5T42p/2/).

Comment: Use `Math.floor()` instead of `parseInt()` if you want to remove the decimal part of a number. (Which basically takes us back to my answer)
[jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-math-floor)

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident that the difference will be less that 24 hours, the following works.

```
var timeStart= new Date('2015-01-01 03:45:45.890');
var timeEnd = new Date('2015-01-01 05:12:34.567');
var timeDiff = new Date(timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime());
var humanTime = timeDiff.toISOString().substring(11, 23);
var diffHours = timeDiff.toISOString().substring(11, 12);
```

humanTime is 01:26:48.677, diffHours is 01

Answer (score 1):

You can Try This:-

```
function diff_hours(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= (60 * 60);         // For Hours
  //diff /= (60);          For Minutes
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));

 }

dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
dt2 = new Date(2014,10,3);
console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));            // you will get '24' hours


dt1 = new Date("October 13, 2014 08:11:00");
dt2 = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));           // you will get '3' hours
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeDiff = function (date1, date2) {
        var a = new Date(date1).getTime(),
            b = new Date(date2).getTime(),
            diff = {};

        diff.milliseconds = a > b ? a % b : b % a;
        diff.seconds = diff.milliseconds / 1000;
        diff.minutes = diff.seconds / 60;
        diff.hours = diff.minutes / 60;
        diff.days = diff.hours / 24;
        diff.weeks = diff.days / 7;

        return diff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Time difference in hours minutes and secons like countdown by using following:

```
var diff = EndedTime - StartedTime;
var hours   = Math.floor(diff / 3.6e6);
var minutes = Math.floor((diff % 3.6e6) / 6e4);
var seconds = Math.floor((diff % 6e4) / 1000);
var duration = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
```

Hope This Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get Time Difference in hours and minutes format like below

```
const startTime = new Date(event.startTime);
const endTime = new Date(event.endTime);
const diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
const hrDiff = diff / 3600 / 1000; // 1.555555
const totalHours = parseFloat((hrDiff).toFixed(2)); // 1.5
```