# Minute duration differentiation javascript

Tags: javascript, date, duration

suppose I have this variable date in hour : minute : second format

```
var time1 = "12:34:19 PM"
var time2 = "12:29:25 PM"
```

How I get the differentiate (duration) from time1 and time2? And how we change it into date format to do diff process?

Comment: And can you share your effort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in minute, hours javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839874/difference-between-two-dates-in-minute-hours-javascript)

Comment: I try a few methods of differentiation date,, and then I juust realize time1 data is String type, so I have to change it to date first... but any effort always end with NaN, such as using strtodate or define php variable

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224459/how-to-create-a-date-object-from-string-in-javascript) as reference. Also remember,  date constructor expects string to be in `MM-DD-YYYY` format. If you are open for libraries, you can look into *moment.js*

Comment: @Rajesh for the duplicates, I've already try the method, however as i said the problem is type data String itself... what is timeEnd and timeStart type data?

Comment: No. Problem is they have datetime string and you have time string. You will have to add date part to compute a valid difference.

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/eze8q7nv/) that gives you difference in seconds without creating date object. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the time new Date() just prepend a date before it and

get their timestamp using `getTime()` and subtract them

```
var duration = new Date('datetime1').getTime() - new Date('datetime2').getTime()
```

since the timestamp is 1000 times than the result total seconds divide it by 1000

```
var duration = durantion/1000;
```

and I just create a function that format the seconds properly to makes it looks like a valid duration time

```js
var time1 = "2016-11-02 12:34:19 PM"
var time2 = "2016-11-02 12:29:25 PM"

time1 = new Date(time1 ).getTime();
time2 = new Date(time2 ).getTime();
var duration = (time1 - time2) / 1000;

function formatTime(seconds) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(((seconds/3600)%1)*60);
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var seconds = Math.round(((seconds/60)%1)*60);
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
  return minutes+':'+seconds;
}

console.log('Duration: ' + formatTime(duration)+' secs')
```

Comment: Please let OP share efforts

Comment: when initialize new Date do we have to input the date month and year? I get a NaN, even when i print time1

Comment: @RayanSuryadikara yes, you must put the date and time `2016-11-02 12:00:00 PM` for example

Answer (score 0):

This is working script

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}
var timeStart = new Date("Mon Jan 01 2007 11:00:00 GMT+0530").getTime();
var timeEnd = new Date("Mon Jan 01 2007 11:32:51 GMT+0530").getTime();
var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; //in ms
var secDiff = (hourDiff / 1000).toString(); //in s
alert(secDiff .toHHMMSS());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Date` objects using constructor like this:
`Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)`

in your case you can get diff:

```
var date = new Date(2000, 1, 1, 12, 34, 19, 0, 0),
    date2 = new Date(2000, 1, 1, 12, 39, 25, 0, 0);

console.log(date2 - date); // in ms. You can do whatever you want with this value
```

you can read more about `Date` object [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)