# Get the difference between two dates in minutes with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I save a `Date()` in the `AsyncStorage` and when I open the app want to compare it to the current Date and check if at least `n` minutes are passed. I found a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839874/difference-between-two-dates-in-minute-hours-javascript) on the forum and tried to follow it

I wrote something like

```
try {
    const lastDate = await AsyncStorage.getItem('lastDate')
    if (lastDate !== null) {
        const currentDate = new Date()
        console.log(currentDate.getTime() - lastDate.getTime())
    }
```

But, I am getting an error telling me that `getTime()` is `undefined`.

Comment: what is `lastUpdateRequestDate `?

Comment: I corrected the code

Comment: So how is lastDate stored in the persistence layer?  Is it already an Epoch Time (numeric) value?

Comment: diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((new Date(currentDate).getTime() - new Date(lastDate).getTime()) / (oneDay))); Here currentDate and lastDate are in string format

Comment: AsyncStorage.getItem('lastDate').then((lastDate) => {
      let CurrentDate = new Date();
      lastDate= new Date(lastDate);
      var start = Math.floor(lastDate.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000));
      var end = Math.floor(CurrentDate.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000));
      var daysDiff = end - start;
      console.log(daysDiff);
      
    })